# WINDOWS - Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python-3.x, windows, bottleneck

> Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I post the answer to such error in case someone comes across it as I did.

The [GitHub Thread](https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/281) does not solves the error for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [PyPy page](https://pypi.org/project/Bottleneck/) suggests:

> To install bottleneck on Windows, first install MinGW and add it to
> your system path. Then install Bottleneck with the command:
>
> python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32 **Alternatively, you can use
> the Windows binaries created by Christoph Gohlke:
> [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bottleneck](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#bottleneck)**

Such wheel solves the issue.